# Remove Blazorise from ABP.io Blazor project or create standalone

Tags: blazor, abp

I am using the generated Blazor WebAssembly project from the ABP CLI tool. Working great until the project getting bigger and one realise that Blazorise and theming is not what you want.

I would like to create a new Blazor WebAssembly project, from the Visual Studio wizard and using the endpoints supported by ABP server side. `Or even better, use ABP.io modules to interact with the server side, but excluding Theming / Blazorise / UI things.`

Can you please help me get started?